# error loading _jsonnet (this is expected on Windows)

Tags: python, anaconda, artificial-intelligence, jupyter

I'm working on an AI model, when trying to predict the data via

> allennlp.predictors.predictor

I get this error

> error loading _jsonnet, treating C: \ wamp \ bin \ php \ PHP55 ~ 1.12 \ ext \ php_intl.dll \ tmpyygczv81 \ config.json

as plain json knowing I have no wamp in my machine, when running it creates me under **c:/** the a w**amp folder,** here are screenshot of my some code
Ps: I am a beginner thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same error. Wondering anyone found a solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same error, you can click [here](https://github.com/google/jsonnet/issues/734)!
Finally, I solved this problem by `pip install jsonnetbin`

Answer (score 0):

A newer version [jsonnet-binary](https://pypi.org/project/jsonnet-binary/) is available, that replaces jsonnetbin.
However still [no support for Windows](https://github.com/google/jsonnet/issues/734) in the official jsonnet at this moment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).